# XAML designer crashed for Windows Universal blank app

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm building a UWP app off the black Visual Studio app template, and I received a `Sytem.TypeLoadException`

> Method 'GetStylePropertyTargetType' in type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Metadata.WindowsUIXamlPlatformMetadata'
>   from assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UniversalXamlDesigner,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=netural,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'does
>   not have an implementation.

Any ideas how to resolve it?

[Picture of Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StITW.png)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: 2nd that, having the same issue and the solution listed below didn't work.  Did you make any progress on this you can share?  Everytime I decide I want to write a XAML app the editor pukes on itself and I end up going back to WinForms. :p

Answer (score 0):

It is a know issue, a suggested solve from [Visual Studio bug tracker](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2539702) and [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe4f3ea0-245d-4189-988d-6759d1d726d2/uwpxaml-designer-failed-to-load-on-vs2015-pro-update-2?forum=visualstudiogeneral&prof=required):

Make sure your Tools for Universal Windows App is running version 1.3

> Programs and features -> Microsoft VS2015 -> Select Change -> Goto
>   Modify and check if the SDK v1.3 need to be installed

If you are missing the latest version you can either try modifying your Visual Studio Installation. Or try downloading and installing the standalone install from [Windows Dev Center](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).